# root path twig restriction

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to set the href value dependig the referer value, but it doesn't work. Am I writing the restriction well?

```
{% if "{{app.request.headers.get('referer')}}" == "{{path('userPurchaseBidGetAll', {companyId: app.user.company.id})}}" %} href="{{path('userPurchaseBidGetAll', {companyId: app.user.company.id})}}"{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is already in a twig logical tag, and so the `{{ }}` tags inside the inverted commas "" will be interpreted as a string. You can just write the logic there:

```
{% if app.request.headers.get('referer') == path('userPurchaseBidGetAll', {companyId: app.user.company.id})%}  href="{{path('userPurchaseBidGetAll', {companyId: app.user.company.id})}}"{% endif %}
```

Inside the twig logical tags you have access to the twig variables (like `app`);

Comment: when I put the three equals I got an exception: Unexpected token "operator" of value "="

Comment: Yes sorry, I confused php syntax with twig one, I will correct that. Thank you!

Comment: I'm still getting nothing I printed the two variables and I get the same result, but the if isn't working fine.

Comment: Are you sure the refer is the same as path? If it's on the same website, it might not be the complete address. Can you add the  {{ dump(app.request.headers.get('referer')) }} {{dump(path('userPurchaseBidGetAll', {companyId: app.user.company.id}))}} and the condition  {{dump(app.request.headers.get('referer') == path('userPurchaseBidGetAll', {companyId: app.user.company.id}))}} ?

Comment: if it isn't working with the code presented, then your strings are not quite equal. One may have whitespace or other contents you don't see when printing. If you can't figure out the difference check http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php